# Cannot connect to nginx on EC2, when it's configured on port different than 80,8090,443

Tags: windows, firewall, port, nginx

I am trying to connect Nginx on EC2 instance (Windows 2008) by using a port "1234".
While nginx configured on port 80, 443, 8090 it works fine, but when I use some different port - I could not connect from remote browser.
Security group configured for the instance (All TCP 0-65535), firewall on Windows is down.
`netstat -ano` shows port 1234 is listening, and I could access when I launch browser on instance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your firewall settings in EC2?

Have a look at your security groups and make sure the ports you are trying to use are open:
[image]